# Gitlab-CI, Maven and Java 10: build always fail - cannot find symbol

Tags: java, maven, gitlab-ci, java-10

You can check the full project here: https://gitlab.com/tyvain/parcoursup

Build history here: https://gitlab.com/tyvain/parcoursup/pipelines

Since a week gitlab-ci doesn't build anymore. It doesn't look like a code problem, but more a 'path' problem:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project importparcoursup: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /builds/tyvain/parcoursup/src/main/java/nc/unc/importparcoursup/view/AdmisMainView.java:[9,55] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class AdmisRejetRepository
[ERROR]   location: package nc.unc.importparcoursup.dao.admisDAO.repository
[ERROR] /builds/tyvain/parcoursup/src/main/java/nc/unc/importparcoursup/view/components/InformationComponent.java:[7,55] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class AdmisRejetRepository
[ERROR]   location: package nc.unc.importparcoursup.dao.admisDAO.repository
[ERROR] /builds/tyvain/parcoursup/src/main/java/nc/unc/importparcoursup/view/AdmisMainView.java:[30,37] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class AdmisRejetRepository
[...]
```

**The build works locally (on windows).**

I tried to upgrade the docker image and tried to look in history what could be wrong. But so far I have no idea why it fails.

Comment: The build error is quite clear; the `AdmisRejetRepository` class cannot be found.

Comment: If that class was part of your project; check if it has been removed recently. If it comes from a third party jar, check if you bumped the dependency version (and roll it back to the latest known working version..)

Comment: the build is working locally (with the same mvn command). The class is in my project and has not been removed.

Comment: Ok, if it builds locally then maybe the build is referencing an old snapshot jar; and you have removed that class afterwise? Or maybe it has been moved to another jar? At any rate, your class is not available in Gitlab at https://gitlab.com/tyvain/parcoursup/tree/master/src/main/java/nc/unc/importparcoursup/dao/admisDAO/repository , an that explains why the build fails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problems started with [commit](https://gitlab.com/tyvain/parcoursup/commit/3709bcafa9bb5a9825b6388855d803555b17c9a4) and the corrisponding [build](https://gitlab.com/tyvain/parcoursup/-/jobs/111344612) failed

When i check your files at https://gitlab.com/tyvain/parcoursup/find_file/master  there is no `PreCandidature` or `AdmisRejetRepository`

Maybe you just forgot to add the files to git?
Maybe they are ignored?

Comment: ok my bad, I switch to intellij and the 'included git system' doesn't add new files....